# PHP driver for MSSQL in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on docker. Now I need to connect to a remote MSSQL server using PHP. After following the instruction to install PHP driver from Microsoft and various websites, I still got the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 in /root/getDbStatus.php:15
```

I installed `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` using `pecl` command, added extension ini to `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/` manually, and created soft links to `/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are some packages information.

[image]

[image] printed from phpinfo().

I also noticed that my odbc driver file is actually empty, and I have no idea why's that.

[image]

Did I miss something here?

Comment: You seem to have installed it only for the CLI version. Do you only need CLI access? Does a php page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` show the extension enabled?

Comment: I see `sqlsrv support => enabled` and `pdo_sqlsrv support => enabled` so I think it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found what I missed here.
Other than `unixodbc-dev` package, I also need to install `msodbcsql17`.
[image]

Thanks everyone for your time.